# In T-SQL on SQL Server 2016, how do I reference the data after the @ in the data.extendedProperty?

Tags: json, sql-server

I receive the following json from an vendor API call. I can pull the `data.extendedProprty` into a `varchar` column, but then I need to add code to break it down into `entityId`, reference. Is there a simpler way to have SQL reference that data?

Sample code

```
[
    {
        "data":  {
                     "extendedProperty":  "@{entityId=a56e2696-03ea-4550-8bd4-e52e52a49f9f; reference=/reference/extendedProperty/a56e2696-03ea-4550-8bd4-e52e52a49f9f; body=}",
                     "name":  "A",
                     "displayOrder":  2
                 },
        "id":  {
                   "entityId":  "6d960f08-1a6c-4b10-a8ab-dd6ce8cf5126",
                   "entityVersion":  1,
                   "entityOrigin":  "BulkUpload",
                   "createdOn":  "2015-04-29T18:51:31.77",
                   "deleted":  false
               }
    },
    {
        "data":  {
                     "extendedProperty":  "@{entityId=f658af92-cb88-4f3d-9e71-e436e445a158; reference=/reference/extendedProperty/f658af92-cb88-4f3d-9e71-e436e445a158; body=}",
                     "name":  "B",
                     "displayOrder":  2
                 },
        "id":  {
                   "entityId":  "71cc0553-1d33-45b5-9097-2d0dbc11d84d",
                   "entityVersion":  1,
                   "entityOrigin":  "BulkUpload",
                   "createdOn":  "2018-12-10T21:44:38.607",
                   "deleted":  false
               }
    }
]
```

Comment: What syntax is that string? It's not JSON, and I'm not familiar with it at all. You are probably going to need somthing like `STRING_SPLIT` and `CHARINDEX`

Comment: @iLWR why do you want to "split" this in SQL? I recommend to do this on your application layer not on your data layer. Somehow you call this API right? Which technology do you use here?